# Moving files within codeblocks project

Tags: codeblocks

So this might be outright stupid question, but I found no answer looking on the internet or fiddling with different buttons.

Say you have a project with several physical folders which contain different source files. Now you've decided that you'll create a new folder and move parts of three old ones in there.

In order to do so, I had to do the following:

1. Go into my project folder via explorer and create a new folder
2. Manually move all the desired files into that folder
3. Return to code blocks and remove all the moved files from the project
4. Re-add all the removed files by selecting the whole new folder when adding existing files
5. Manually going through code and modifying all affected include directives to point to the proper path

It would be much simpler if you could right-click a folder, create a new nested folder and just drag-and-drop files to where you want them while code blocks would move them on disk and correct the includes for me.

It's the way that Eclipse does it for Java. Is there similar functionality for code blocks, maybe a plugin?

Comment: Code::Blocks seems to be _very_ limited in functionality.

Comment: That is why I moved to VS soon after this question was asked. ;)